# Textview dispalys "androidx.livecycle.CoroutineLiveData"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to display the sum of a column from my room database in a textview.
After implementing my Query and setting the text of the Textview, it displays the following:

androidx.lifecycle.CoroutineLiveData@76f6edd

Any idea why this happens? Is it because my Query does not work or my way of implementign it is wrong?
It is my first time ever of actually programming. I know probably most of my code is not 100% correct, but I am working on it.

The Query from my Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(total)AS sum_total FROM receipt_table")
    fun getSum(): Flow<Float>
```

The Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HistoryFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_history) {

private val viewModel: PurchaseViewmodel by viewModels()


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentHistoryBinding.bind(view)

    val exampleAdapter = ExampleAdapter()

    binding.apply{
        recyclerView.apply{

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = exampleAdapter

        }
        totalSumTextView.apply {
            val totalSum = viewModel.totalSum
            text = totalSum.toString()
        }
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false 
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val receipt = exampleAdapter.currentList[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
                 viewModel.onSwipe(receipt)
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    setFragmentResultListener("add_receipt_request"){_,bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getInt("add_receipt_request")
        viewModel.onAddResult(result)
    }

    viewModel.receipts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ 
        exampleAdapter.submitList(it)
    }


    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.addTaskEvent.collect {  event->
            when(event){
                is PurchaseViewmodel.TasksEvent.ShowUndoDelete -> {
                    Snackbar.make(requireView(),"Tasks deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("UNDO"){
                            viewModel.unDoDeleteClick(event.receipts)
                        }.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the Viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PurchaseViewmodel @Inject constructor(
private val receiptDao: ReceiptDao
    ): ViewModel() {
private val tasksEventChannel = Channel<TasksEvent>()
val addTaskEvent = tasksEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()
val receipts = receiptDao.getAllReceipts().asLiveData()
val totalSum = receiptDao.getSum().asLiveData()

fun onAddResult(result: Int){
    when (result){
        ADD_RECEIPT_RESULT_OK ->showReceiptSavedConfirmation("Receipt has been saved")
    }
}
private fun showReceiptSavedConfirmation (text: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    tasksEventChannel.send(TasksEvent.ShowReceiptSavedConfirmation(text))
}

fun onSwipe (receipts: Receipts) = viewModelScope.launch {
    receiptDao.delete(receipts)
    tasksEventChannel.send(TasksEvent.ShowUndoDelete(receipts))
}
fun unDoDeleteClick (receipts: Receipts) = viewModelScope.launch {
    receiptDao.insert(receipts)
}

sealed class TasksEvent {
    data class ShowReceiptSavedConfirmation(val msg: String) : TasksEvent()
    data class ShowUndoDelete(val receipts: Receipts) : TasksEvent()
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `LiveData` object here, not just a value:

```
 val totalSum = receiptDao.getSum().asLiveData()
```

When you call:

```
totalSum.toString()
```

It calls `toString` method on the `LiveData` object that the reason, why you have "androidx.lifecycle.CoroutineLiveData@76f6edd" inside your `TextView`.

To fix the issue, just replace:

```
 totalSumTextView.apply {
            val totalSum = viewModel.totalSum
            text = totalSum.toString()
        }
```

with:

```
viewModel.totalSum.observe(this) { totalSumTextView.text = it}
```

Detailed review, how to work with a `LiveData` you can find here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation! I added your function but get the error that the inferred type is Float! but CharSequence! was expected. 
I changed the Dao Query to Flow<String>, but it's still the same issue. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, a simple toString() solved it. Thanks a lot!